# How do I simplify to load some files in the corona?

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I am new to corona, all the work is from a scratch of others. Let see, I have 3 images that entitled **shop1price shop2price shop3price**. Now I want it to be simplified as the code below

```
local options =
{
    { defaultFile = 'images/shop1price.png' },
    { defaultFile = 'images/shop2price.png' },
    { defaultFile = 'images/shop3price.png' },
}

local priceTag = {}
for i = 1,3 do
    priceTag[i] = widget.newButton{
        options[i],
        overColor = {128,128,128,255},
        width = 73,
        height = 38,
        left = (centerX-155) + (i-1)*118,
        top = centerY * 0.88,
        id = i,
        onEvent = function (e) 
            if e.phase == 'ended' then
                onTouchBuy(e.target.id)
            end
            return true 
        end
    }
    -- priceTag[i] : setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
    priceTag[i] : scale( 0.8 , 0.8 )
    buttonGroup : insert( priceTag[i] )
end
```

But the button does not appear, I think the wrong is in `options[i]`. But the problem always is I don't know how the right. I know I can make the code themselves one by one, but it is certainly very tiring. What if I have for example of 100 buttons.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 local options = {}

  [#options+1] =   'images/shop1price.png'
  [#options+1] =   'images/shop2price.png'
  [#options+1] =   'images/shop3price.png'


local priceTag = {}
for i = 1,#options  do
   priceTag[i] = widget.newButton{
      defaultFile = options[i],
      overColor = {128,128,128,255},
      width = 73,
      height = 38,
      left = (centerX-155) + (i-1)*118,
      top = centerY*0.88,
      id = i,
      onEvent = function (e) 
         if e.phase == 'ended' then
            onTouchBuy(e.target.id)
         end
         return true 
     end
   }
  -- priceTag[i] : setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
   priceTag[i] : scale( 0.8 , 0.8 )
   buttonGroup : insert( priceTag[i] )
end
```

Try this , should work fine.